# How to get current user from ServiceStack.Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, servicestack, log4net

I am using ASP.NET MVC and [servicestack.logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging)
I used log4net.

I need to get current user who has been authenticated by servicestack-jwt.

With below code in my webconfig, I just get **windows** current user.

```
  <appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="User_Log">
  <file value="C:\logging\user_log\" />
  <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <header type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="[START LOG] %newline" />
     <footer type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="[END LOG] %newline" />
    <conversionPattern value="[%property{log4net:HostName}] - [%username] - [%identity] - [%w] -%identity%newline%utcdate - %-5level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
```

I also used below code in Global.asax

```
       protected void Application_Start()
    {

        ServiceStack.Logging.LogManager.LogFactory = new ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetFactory(true);

        //I can save test
        Logger.InfoFormat("test");

        string name = "";
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context != null && context.User != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            name = context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        //I can NOT save name
        _logger.InfoFormat(name);

    }
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/), the Authenticated User is [stored in the UserSession](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) which is accessible from `IRequest.GetSession()`. If using an AppHost like ASP.NET Framework which maintains the current HttpContext in a `HttpContext.Current` singleton, it can be accessed with:

```
var req = HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest();
var session = req.GetSession();
var userName = session.UserAuthName;
```